Adding custom domain from hostinger to azure app service
I have been trying to deploy a personal project on the azure app service. I got a domain from the hostinger and have done the following things.

I added the custom domain to the app service, validated by adding IP and asuid to A record and TXT record respectively.
binded the certificates
I tried adding CNAME as well

but for some reason, it is giving me 400 Bad request error.
Am I missing anything?

Have you tried any other approach. @Gaurish Ninnekar

I tried with custom DNS Zones and changed the default Name servers but still the issue was same, I thought it might take some time to reflect the changes but It still persist to show the same error. got any suggestions?

Checking on it. Have you given the configuration correctly. @Gaurish Ninnekar

Yup! I checked the records couple of times and everything is appropriately configured.
like, A records for adding the ip and TXT for the verification Id. Deliberately I added CNAME as well, just to keep the things in check.

Have you tried checking the DNS configuration with nslookup? @Gaurish Ninnekar

Yeah, I checked using nslookup and was I getting the right IP. The problem was in the code. I had used environment variable for allowed hosts, but I had to add the domain from the hostinger to the environment variable(ALLOWED_HOSTS) as well. Thanks for helping though.

Do you want me to post the answer for other community benefit. @Gaurish Ninnekar

400 Bad request error when adding a custom domain to azure app service comes in various scenarios. Check below causes and steps to resolve it.
As detailed here in MS Doc, there are few custom domain problems may occur related to 400 error codes. Missing a "CNAME record" or an "A record" on the custom domain might lead to this conflict. As you mentioned, you have already added it, check again and ignore if it is added properly.
The issue can also cause if you haven't added the new custom domain in "ALLOWED_HOSTS" variable inside the settings script.
As @Gaurish Ninnekar pointed in the right direction, make sure that it is included it in the settings file to avoid any conflicts. Refer Microsoft Q&A for the same relevant issue.
Verify that the TL/SSL bindings are binded to the created custom certificate as shown below. You can reverify it by visiting custom domains in the App service as shown. Check that HTTPS Only is enabled if you are using HTTPS call.

Most importantly, if you have applied any changes restart your Azure App Service to make sure that all changes are properly reflected and configured.
